# JS client/Python server XMLHttpRequest post with data cannot load due to access control checks

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a Python server and a JavaScript client.

The server has to get some data in a certain post request.
Testing it with:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"name":"test"}' "https://server_url/op?param=p"
```

Works perfectly.

If I call the server from the client with:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4)  {
    // Do some stuff
  }
};
xhttp.open('POST', 'server_url/op?param=p', true);
xhttp.send();
```

It also works perfectly, but of course, responds that it is missing the data. However, if I call the server with this:

```
 xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({'name': 'test'}));
```

I keep getting a "cannot load due to access control checks" error with the server not responding... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the browser developer tools console, do you see an error regarding CORS? if `server_url` is a different domain than your web page, then you can only get cross origin resources if the other server allows it - check your developer tools console, if it's a CORS error, you'll need to *proxy* the request via your own *server*

Comment: Doesn't with fetch either...

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because fetch doesn't do anything different to XHR, it just does things better

Comment: If it were server CORS error wouldn't that happen with `xhttp.send()` and cUrl too?
In any case the server responds with the `self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` header...

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise you were NOT getting a CORS error ... you answered my question about CORS with "Doesn't with fetch either" ... so I didn't realise you were NOT getting a CORS error - are you SURE you're not getting an error regarding an "OPTIONS" request once you added the `'Content-Type', 'application/json'` header? Because that triggers a CORS preflight OPTIONS request that needs to be handled by the server

Comment: Yeah sorry, I posted it the second you did so I didn't see your comment when I wrote it :) Oh and yes it's probably OPTIONS. Forgot about it... checking...

Comment: The issue is likely the CORS preflight - it's an OPTIONS request (as opposed to GET or POST) - the server needs to respond to OPTIONS request for correct CORS handling

Comment: So for some reason the do_OPTIONS was missing from the server... Added it and everything works :) @JaromandaX, if you want to post it as an answer so I could upvote you. Thanks!